# How to use GTFS to record or analyse operating time series?

Tags: time-series, gtfs

I may be wrong but GTFS is mainly used to plan or describe a public transportation system and GTFS-realtime is mainly used to make realtime operation data available. I think I need something that is not contemplated by none of these frameworks.

I need to record operational data like, how many passenger were transported, how much they paid, when each trip left the initial stop, etc. Data that must be recorded daily and kept in a database for latter use.

Does GTFS somehow address this?

Comment: Persistence of events extracted from GTFS feeds could be better accomplished using a time-series database or even aggregator such as elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Using a GTFS and a GTFS-realtime feed together you should be able to identify when a trip departed from its origin and whether it was on-time. If your transit agency includes "alert" data in its GTFS-realtime feed you may also be able to identify exceptional events that affect particular trips, such as roadwork or collisions.

Beyond that, I think you will have to look for other sources for the data you need (most likely the transit agency itself).

GTFS data describes the static features of a transit network, including its stops, routes and timetables. A GTFS-realtime feed provides live, operational data, but data of the sort riders can use to know when their bus will be arriving, not data transit operators track internally like ridership and fare revenues.